# NCrawler doesn't crawl beyond first url even though MaxCrawlDepth > 1

Tags: web-crawler

[NCrawler](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com) doesn't crawl beyond first url even though MaxCrawlDepth > 1. So if I put yahoo.com and MaxCrawlDepth = 3, it crawls that page only and it stops. I also verified this using a packet sniffer when the only address it went to was yahoo.com.

How do I get it to crawl every link in a page? (I don't have time to check the source code)

Answer (score 0):

NCrawler expects a completely formed URL. Try replacing the url with http://www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

This happens on my side when I add HTMLAgilityPack, check to see if you have it and remove it.